# Find median with given frequency of number

Tags: sql, sql-server

Wanted to write a SQL Server query to find median with given frequency of number.

Table:

```
+----------+-------------+
|  number  |  frequency  |
+----------+-------------|
|  2       |  7          |
|  3       |  1          |
|  5       |  3          |
|  7       |  1          |
+----------+-------------+
```

In this table, the numbers are `2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 7` so the median is `(2 + 2) / 2 = 2`

I have created the following query using recursive CTE [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7609c3/2), is there a better way to write this one with more efficiency?

My solution:

```
/* recursive CTE to generate numbers with given frequency */

with nums as
(
    select
        number,
        frequency
    from numbers

    union all

    select
        number,
        frequency - 1
    from nums
    where frequency > 1
)

/* find median */

select
    round(avg(number * 1.0), 2) as median
from
(
    select
        number,
        count(*) over () as ttl,
     row_number() over (order by number) as rnk
    from nums
) t
where rnk = (case when ttl%2 != 0 then (ttl/2) else (ttl/2)+1 end)
or rnk = (case when ttl%2 = 0 then (ttl/2)+1 end)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do a cumulative sum and take the middle value.  I think this is the logic:

```
select avg(number)
from (select t.*,
             sum(freq) over (order by number asc) as sum_freq,
             sum(freq) over () as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt <= 2 * sum_freq and
      cnt >= 2 * (sum_freq - freq);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=99033095d21fb52d83f9d7d2eb2ee899) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: in case of even cnt (items in the dataset) the where condition will return the lower half (eg for values (1,4), (3,4) only 1 would be returned, avg(1)=1 while median is 2)... maybe change the where to `sum_freq >= ceiling(cnt/2.) and sum_freq-freq <= floor(cnt/2.)` ?

Comment: @lptr . . . I updated it.  I actually tested this, a lot.  I just miscounted what was even and odd.  Here is an example:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c75acb052a4ecbaad69ce68d6928f6c4.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably too late to reply nonetheless here is my approach to finding Median from a given frequency table. This covers both odd and even scenarios.

```
`-- 1. Create a frequency table witth the Price and its frequency
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#MedianEX', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #MedianEX;
create table #MedianEX (Price  int,Frequency int)
insert into #MedianEX values(2 ,3)
insert into #MedianEX values(3,7)
insert into #MedianEX values(4,2)
insert into #MedianEX values(6,5 )
insert into #MedianEX values(5,6 )
insert into #MedianEX values(7,2 )


--uncomment the below statement to make total number of element = 24(even number scenario)
update #MedianEx  set Frequency=5 where Price=5

--calculate (n-1)/2 th position and (n+1)/2 th position if odd  value and n/2 th position if even
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #temp;
select  *,SUM(Frequency)over (order by Price asc)as cmfreq,ceiling(SUM(Frequency) over()/2.0) as UCNT,
floor(SUM(Frequency) over()/2.0) as LCNT into #temp from #MedianEX

--select price value at the required positions and calculate their average
select cast(avg(Price * 1.0) as decimal(10,2)) from (
select top 1 Price from #temp where  UCNT<=cmfreq 
union
select top 1 Price from #temp where  LCNT<=cmfreq) t

--select * from #MedianEX`
```